# how to write plugin with setInterval in it

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, setinterval

I'm trying to write a plugin.my jQuery is not good.and I read many examples my english is not good...so I did not understand them very well.
please help me and if you can explain simple.

here is my code:

HTML:

```
    <div class="coming back-countdown">
        <h1>WWW.<span id="spin">STACKOVERFLOW</span>.COM</h1>
    </div>
```

javacript:

```
;   
(function($) {
    $fn.myPlugin = function() {
        var settings = $.extend({
            beforeStop: 2000;
            betweenStop: 500;
            charChangeInterval: 100;
        });

        function repeat() {
            var $this = $(this);
            var origText = $this.text(), newText = '';
            var myArr = origText.split("");
            var text = origText.split("");
            for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                var handle = setInterval(function (i) {
                    myArr[i] = String.fromCharCode(Math.random() * 26 + 65);
                    $this.text(myArr.join(""));
                }, charChangeInterval, i);
                setTimeout(function (handle, i) {
                    clearInterval(handle);
                    myArr[i] = text[i];
                    $this.text(myArr.join(""));
                }, i * betweenStop + beforeStop, handle, i);
            }
        }
        repeat();
        setInterval(repeat,20000);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: What is the specific problem and question?

Comment: It does not work.I dont know how to pass defaults.and I dont know it is the right way to call a function and use setinterval.

Answer (score 0):

To have default settings and enabling user to override them, see how to do that over here: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/

To call the plugin you have created use:

```
$.myPlugin({beforeStop:1000}); // running the plugin and overriding beforeStop
```

And then you have a repeat function. Add the bottom you call it properly, directly and via setInterval. Within the function you do some interesting stuff but I am sure whatever you want to do there can be done much simpler. If you would like help on that, please specify what you are trying to do.